# Characterization of an interval of the real line

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that given $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$

$S$ is an interval iff $$(\forall x, y)(x, y \in S \quad \text{and} \quad x<y \implies [x, y] \subseteq S)$$

**First implication**: This implication seems not difficult to appreciate, I think it is ideal for cases:

1. If $S=[a, b]$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, let $x, y \in S$ with $x < y$, for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $z \in [x, y]$ we have that
   $$a \leq x\leq z \leq y \leq b$$
   By transitivity it is not difficult to see that $a \leq z \leq b$ then $z \in S$
2. If $S=(a, b)$, the same but changing the inequalities

"for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, let $x, y \in S$ with $x < y$, for $z \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $z \in [x, y]$ we have that
$$a < x\leq z \leq y < b$$
By transitivity it is not difficult to see that $a < z < b$ then $z \in S$"

actually the two remaining cases $S=[a, b)$ and $S=(a, b]$ are a copy and paste of the above.

**Second implication**: I will try to make the case that  $S=(a, b)$ and the other cases should be analogous.

If we want to prove that $S$ is an interval, particularly in the form $(a, b)$, we should find $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ s.t. for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$ if
$$a<z<b$$
then $z \in S$ and if $z<a$ or $b<z$ then $z \notin S$ This should be what characterizes this type of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$.

We can choose $a= \inf {S}$ and $b=sup {S}$,  this choice is guaranteed by the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, $S$ should be bounded if $a \neq - \infty$ and $b\neq \infty$.

This is where my doubts begin, by actual density could choose $z \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $a<z<b$?

From here on how can I guarantee that $z \in S$ I'm not really convinced by this, as it seems almost obvious by hypothesis.

On the other hand if $z<a$ then $z$ is lower and because it is at infimum we have that $z \notin S$ which contradicts, we can analogously see that $z<b$

I don't see the reciprocal very clearly, any suggestions or help?

I appreciate it!

Comment: if $z \in S$ then by definition of $\inf$ then there exists $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $a + \varepsilon \in S$ and $a < a + \varepsilon < z$. An analogous thing can be said for $b$ and you can use your hypothesis.

Comment: @Zag And what does this concretely lead me to? could you explain this a little more, I don't fully understand the idea.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to prove that $S = (a, b)$ given that $a = \inf S$, $b = \sup S$, $a, b \notin S$ and $S$ has the property you give at the start? You can prove that $(a, b) \subseteq S$ by taking $z \in (a, b)$, and choosing $x \in S$ with $x \le z$, and $y \in S$ with $y \ge z$. Such an $x$ exists because otherwise $z$ would be a lower bound for $S$, contradicting the fact that $a$ is the infimum. Similarly such a $y$ must exist.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen The other contention $S \subseteq (a, b)$ is almost immediate or something like that? it is not very clear to me

Comment: $S \subseteq [a, b]$ because $a$ is a lower bound for $S$ (it's the infimum) and $b$ is an upper bound (it's the supremum). $S \subseteq (a, b)$ because $a, b \notin S$ (which you have to assume at this point - the four cases $(a, b)$, $(a, b]$, $[a, b)$ and $[a, b]$ correspond to the four choices for $a$, $b$ being/not being in $S$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I see, thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a:=\inf S,b:=\sup S\in[-\infty,+\infty].$ By definition of $\inf$ and $\sup$, we have $S\subseteq[a,b].$ There only remains to prove that (under the additional "betweeness hypothesis") $(a,b)\subseteq S$ (this will treat your four cases simultaneously).

Let $z\in(a,b).$ Since $z$ is greater than $a,$ it is not a lower bound for $S,$ i.e. $\exists x\in S,~x<z.$ Similarly, since $z<b:$ $\exists y\in S,~y>z.$ By the betweeness property, we conclude: $z\in S,$ which ends the proof.